# K8s ingress-nginx redirecting to 443 intermittently

Tags: kubernetes, nginx, kubernetes-helm, nginx-ingress, ingress-controller

I have a k8s cluster created via terraform on openstack, while creating cluster we have created ingress controller resource using below code:

```
resource "null_resource" "create_ingress_controller" {
  provisioner "remote-exec" {
    connection {
      host        = "${openstack_compute_instance_v2.master.access_ip_v4}"
      user        = "root"
      private_key = "${file(var.ssh_key_file)}"
    }

    inline = [
      "helm upgrade --install ingress-nginx ingress-nginx --repo https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx"
    ]
  }
```

Now a springboot service is deployed to this cluster using helmchart. This service is having following ingress resource:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: {{ .Values.componentName }}-ingress
  labels:
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "false"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/force-ssl-redirect: "false"
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  rules:
    - http:
        paths:
          - path: "{{ .Values.appBaseUri }}"
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: {{ .Values.componentName }}-service
                port:
                  number: {{ .Values.servicePort }}
      host: {{ .Values.ingressDomain }}
    - http:
        paths:
          - path: "{{ .Values.appBaseUri }}/healthcheck"
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: {{ .Values.componentName }}-service
                port:
                  number: {{ .Values.healthcheckPort }}
      host: {{ .Values.ingressDomain }}
```

Ideally when we call this api, it nginx should connect to port 80 but it keeps connecting to 443 port intermittently and sometime it connects to port 80.